# How to set specified gem version for Ruby app?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I`ve encountered the problem after updating some gems, so basically all older gems are still available but i cant force application use them.

Lets say, i need something like that:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mygem', '0.1.2'
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'activerecord', '=1.15.3'
```

This worked for me.

Check this out. Seemed helpful
[Link](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=16739&group_id=126&atid=575)

Answer (score 4):

Well, always happens to me. Found an answer.

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'mygem', '=0.1.2'
```

Comment: @Damien It's not necessarily a rails app.

@Dan Do you not have to require the gem after setting the version?

Comment: well, i didnt say anything about rails. it is not even web application.